# how to use the same function to prompt different mesages to the user?

Tags: java

and thank you in advance for your help.
I need to design a program for the assignment of this week, and the problem is:
Design a modular program using pseudo-code which prompts a user for their first name, followed by their last name; then displays a "Hello" salutation which concatenates their first name with their last name. Sample output (user input is shown in red):

```
Please enter your first name: John
Please enter your last name: Smith
Hello, John Smith!
```

So far, so good, but my problem is the requirements for the assignment. 
My program must include a main module and one function; this function prompts the user for either their first name or last name, using a prompt which is a String parameter passed to the function.

This is the part that really confuses me, and this from my textbook "In other words, your main module should call the function twice, first passing a prompt string for the user's first name, followed by a second call which passes a prompt string for the user's last name. Declare named constants to serve as the prompts which are passed to the function.

The main module then constructs and displays the salutation using the first and last name strings returned by the function. Your salutation should include the word Hello, followed by a comma, followed by the user's first name, space, the user's last name, and an exclamation point, as shown in the Sample Output above."

This is the code I came up with, but I am 100% sure that it does not meet the requirements of the problem

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 

    System.out.println("Please, enter your first name: "); 
    final String firstName = keyboard.next(); 

    System.out.println("Please, enter your last name: "); 
    final String lastName = keyboard.next(); 

    System.out.println("Hello," + userFullName(firstName, lastName) + "!"); 

    public static String userFullName(String firstName, String lastName){ 
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }

}
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks again

Comment: Could you please share bit of your code.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what exactly is confusing you? The assignment is a step-by-step instruction what to do, so it would help if you said which step causes trouble.

Comment: Thank you so much for your replay daniel. This is my first programming class so I hope that my question is not too silly. The part that confuses me is: the program should have one main module and only one function. That function should be called twice in the main module asking the user for either their name or last name. How can I call the function in my main module and at the same time use my function to pass the value of the user name to my function?

Comment: This is the code I came up with, but I am 100% sure that it does not meet the requirements of the problem. Here is the code: package com.company;

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please, enter your first name: ");
        final String firstName = keyboard.next();

        System.out.println("Please, enter your last name: ");
        final String lastName = keyboard.next();

        System.out.println("Hello," + userFullName(firstName, lastName) + "!");

    public static String userFullName(String firstName, String lastName){
        return firstName + " " + lastName;}

Comment: Please [edit] you Question to include any code. Code is not easily readable in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it right, the part that confuses you is how can you just have one main module and one function at the same time.

This is solved with classes. You may have a `MainClass` with a `main` module and a function which you call twice.

An example of pseudo-code for this (as I don't want to do your assignment for you) would be like the following

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        askName("first"); // here would you save firstName into a variable
        askName("last"); // here would you save lastName into another variable
        // here would you output both variables and do the greeting.
    }

    public static String askName(final String name) {
        System.out.println("Please, give your " + name + " name");
        // here goes keyboard input 
        // you have to give back the input you receive  
    }

}
```

This way, you have just one `main` module with a `function` you call twice from it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, Mario. I have no words to express my gratitude for your help, but I am still a little confused. If my main module calls the function twice how I prompt the user for the first name and then with the same function, I prompt the user for their last name. The output of my program is supposed to be like this: 
Please, enter your first name: Alain 
Please, enter your last name: Garcia
Hello, Alain Garcia!
Do you see my problem? Thank you so much again.

Comment: @Alain I modified my comment. You can give the full output you do to the user as a `String` parameter to the function, so that it changes between the first and the second call and join the `Strings` with the `+` operator.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, Mario. This much be the silliest think for you to reply but let me tell you that I really appreciate your help. I think I get it now. I will post my final code here for you to see it. Thanks

Comment: @Alain may you please mark the answer as accepted if you think it helped you solve your problem?

Comment: Thank you so much again, Mario. You really help me. This is the final code: public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String FIRST_NAME = getUserName("first");
        final String LAST_NAME = getUserName("last");

        System.out.println("Hello, " + FIRST_NAME + " " + LAST_NAME + "!" );
        
    }

    public static String getUserName(String name){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please, enter your " + name + " name:");
        name = keyboard.next();
        return name;
    }
}

Comment: Great, but if you post code here, try to format it. Otherwise it is just unreadable for everyone else in here.